# Update only changed values using coalesce and dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I created a stored procedure to update only the rows of a table that have changed

I used the **SQLSERVER** `coalesce` function.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_only_changed

            @FName varchar(50) = NULL,

            @LName varchar(50) = NULL,

            @CUST_DB VARCHAR(20) 

AS

BEGIN

            DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(255)

            SET @QUERY = 'UPDATE ' + @CUST_DB + '..people SET LastName = COALESCE(@LName, LastName) WHERE id = 1'

            EXEC (@QUERY)

END

GO
```

**Some considerations**

- Is a dynamic sql
- The name of the database is passed as a parameter in the procedure

So,  When I run the sql I have two situations:

- `EXEC(@ QUERY)`:

  ```
  I get the error saying: Must declare the scalar variable "@ LName".
  it does not interpret the variable that the command coalesce
  ```
- `EXEC @QUERY   (without parentheses)`

  ```
   I get the error saying: The database 'UPDATE CUSTOMER' does not exist. Make sure the name is spelled correctly.
  ```

how can i put that to work ?

Remember, if a run the procedure with the update statement static, without EXEC, it works

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER..people SET LastName = COALESCE(@LName, LastName) WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Ricardo, did you took into consideration, that this UPDATE will ALWAYS update row upon execution? If you want to update to perform only if @LName is different than current value of LastName then you need to put additional condition on your constructed query.

Comment: @Kuba Wyrostek the function `coalesce` aready to that with the variable, i dont neet to make a condition.

Comment: No, it does not. It either updates LastName column with @LName value or current value of LastName column, but it **always** updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one doesn't work because there is no variable @Lname in the context of the exec - it only exists in your procedure's scope. You need to pass it into the scope of the query by using `sp_executesql` instead of exec

```
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@LName varchar(50)', @Lname
```

**BUT**

I wouldn't recommend doing anything at all like this.

Comment: how can i do that ? can you make a example ?

Comment: Works, but why you dont recommend ?